# Count of pair occerence in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table

```
id  cast_1  cast_2
1     A       R
2     B       K
3     C       L
4     B       K
5     A       R
6     B       k
```

Now I want to get count of pair occurrence from this table
Like for B-K - 3, A-R - 2, C-L 1 with order.

How to write mysql query to get this result?

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.

Comment: `SELECT cast_1, cast_2, count(*) FROM your_table GROUP BY cast_1, cast_2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

USE GrOUP bY

```
select cast_1,cast_2, COUNT(*) Count FROM #TableName
GROUP BY cast_1,cast_2
order by Count desc
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Count(*) FROM table GROUP BY cast_1, cast_2
```